# How to undersand **OperationTimeout** for C# MongoDB Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Could someone give any guides about **OperationTimeout** setting?

I cannot found any clues for this setting in Mongo-CSHARP-Driver Official Docs.

Also, i've searched the Source Code: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/search?q=OperationTimeout&unscoped_q=OperationTimeout and seems no usage for this setting.

Thanks

Comment: Having searched their entire codebase, it seems OperationTimeout is never used. It's assigned, unit tested, never used. Strange. What do you need this for? (ok, I know it's an obvious question...)

Comment: Thanks danielle. Just curious to see it in the Code. I've also heard that they're going to remove this setting for comming v2.7.0_beta1: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/commit/93074a9d2f2d2a9234c2a5c61c16e6d7a52cbf21. The latest for the driver is v2.6.1. see this jira: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1193. But for the older version, the question is what the **OperationTimeout** works for?